# How to get the content of a hidden element through Selenium?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I had some problem with getting hidden element.

Trying to get text from a hidden element on the website https://ethlinq.tech . The hidden element is `div[class="sc-klVQfs coyika"]`. It appears when you click on the `button[class="sc-hRJfrW esGfor"]`. Actually, it is necessary to get to this element despite the fact that initially the location of the hidden element is unknown. So the script receives a link to the site and parses the page in order to search for social networks links (which are hidden in this hidden element).

`driver.get_source_page()` and `driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].outerHTML;", body)` do not see this element

Help please, if it's even real

Comment: Element `button[class="sc-hRJfrW esGfor"]` is not present on provided website homepage.

Comment: just because class_name of this button changes constantly. it's a "Start" button on the bottom left

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply done by waiting for visibility of element with locator `'.start-div div[class*=sc]` after click.

After getting container root, you can search for inner menu items by getting element with class `inner-div`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
web = "https://ethlinq.tech"
driver.get(web)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.start-div button'))).click()
menu_container = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.start-div div[class*=sc]')))
menu_items = menu_container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'inner-div')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply bro but the main reason I ask, as I said, is that initially I don't know where the hidden element is located and whether it even exists on this site. in practice, it may be a completely different site with a different hidden element, I do not know its selecrot or text value or location. for example it can be noneth.io, there are hidden elements in the section f.a.q with class name "framer-qioxmi" and I need to get their texts. So, again, my script gets the website link then it should check if there hidden elements and if true it should get value from hidden element.

Comment: You can just search for hidden element in DOM by text by stopping test execution in debug mode after click (when it appeared)

Comment: it would be nice if we immediately received the entire html of the website, but as I understand it, this is impossible without clicking on the hidden element. so far, the only solution I see is clicking on all clickable elements on the site and parsing the text after clicking, but this is not an option at all.

Comment: How I can find hidden element if I don't know his text value or any other value?

Comment: @VladislavVladislav some elements are rendered async after action and doesn't exist in DOM before. So - yes, easiest way is to investigate them in debug mode. If you don't know element text, just stop in debug mode after it become visible and inspect them. Or go trough dom, hovering elements. When element would be highlighted - it's yours.